# Reloading alert Dialog on rotation

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

Hi I have an alert dialog that appears before a sequence of questions. If I rotate the device the alert is reloaded. How would i ensure that this appears just once and doesn't reload every time the device is rotated. I am happy enough for it to appear if person exits the app and comes back.

Comment: In which method of what Activity/Fragment do you initiate and show the AlertDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use viewmodel with the activity/fragment it can survive the config changes like screen rotation
Link : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: This is the recommended way to store state in modern android apps. +1

Answer (score -3):

use this code in your manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
```

Comment: As stated by @Qunata in a previous answer this should not be used. Der Android documentation recommends only to use this as a last resort.